# nesting rows for nested comments with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create nested comments. When I do not use bootstrap grid system, its fine. But I am using the grid system now because I have an image and a panel that I want to keep in the same row, and the rows are getting messed up.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/ng3f5596/2/) fiddle shows how I want it to look (it just doesnt have the up and down arrows).

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/9d8obcd1/3/) is what it looks like with the grid system and is getting messed up.

Here is the html:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="col-md-12>
    <div class="row comment root" id="1"> 
        <div  class="col-xs-1 arrows-block">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png" name="up" class="img-responsive resize">
                <img src="http://www.lowcountryren.com/nestor/Documentation/ionicons-1.4.1/png/512/arrow-down-b.png" name="down" class="img-responsive resize">
            </div> <!-- pull right -->
        </div><!-- col -->
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  username 1
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  text 1
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0)">reply</a></li>
                        <li><a class="expand" href="javascript:void(0)"> expand</a></li>
                        <li><a class="delete" href="javascript:void(0)"> delete</a></li>
                        <li><a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0)"> edit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- footer -->
           </div><!-- panel-->
    </div><!-- col -->
    <div class="row comment root" id="1">
        <div  class="col-xs-1 arrows-block">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-up-b-128.png" name="up" class="img-responsive resize">
                <img src="http://www.lowcountryren.com/nestor/Documentation/ionicons-1.4.1/png/512/arrow-down-b.png" name="down" class="img-responsive resize">
            </div>
        </div><!-- col -->
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  username 2
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    reply 1
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0)">reply</a></li>
                        <li><a class="expand" href="javascript:void(0)"> expand</a></li>
                        <li><a class="delete" href="javascript:void(0)"> delete</a></li>
                        <li><a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0)"> edit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- footer -->
            </div><!-- panel -->
        </div><!-- col -->
      </div><!-- comment -->
    </div><!-- comment -->
    </div> <!-- big col -->
   </div> <!-- container -->
```

and the css:

```
    .comment{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.resize{
    width:40px;
    height: auto;
}


.col-xs-1{
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: 4%;
}

.col-xs-11{
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.root{
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.arrows-block{
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Basically I want it to look like in the first fiddle linked to but with the down and up arrows right to the left of the panel and I'm not able to do so.

Its as if bootstrap wants to put the next nested comment in the same row.

Any help?

EDIT: I fixed the fiddle link, don't change the fiddle because that is how I want it to look

EDIT: As per [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) a nested row needs to be inside of a column.
I tried wrapping all children elements div class="row comment root" id="1" inside of a  tag and this did not help.
The reason I want to have nested rows is because I want a comment object to have two images and a panel in the same row. Then I want to have a nested comment inside (indented to the left of that comment) also with img tags and a panel in their own same row.

Comment: You are simply missing one closing </div> before your new row <div class="row comment root" id="1">

Comment: I don't want two separate rows. I want a row inside of a row

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</div>` tag before you start a new row
Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9d8obcd1/2/

Comment: Are you sure? I commented which closing tags refer to which opening tags. Where is the mistake/what am I missing? Did you see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ng3f5596/2/) fiddle? This is how I want it to look, with nested comments. Not two separate comments. I want one comment to be indented more than, and a child of, the first comment

Comment: A row in a row. In that case this is expected behavior. What is getting "messed up" according to you?

Comment: Also: just read the bootstrap documentation. There is a section about nesting colums with examples. @user3494047

Comment: In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9d8obcd1/3/) example, I have a row inside a row but the expected behavior is that a new row be created. But what is happening is that it puts the images inside the same upper row. In this example you can see new rows being created [this](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/fbtw6/) example.

Comment: As I said. Read the documentation. In bootstarp nested rows must be defined inside a column. What youre doing is simply wrong. Read read read

Comment: I found the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) on nested rows. That's why I think its not the expected behacior. Ah I see what you mean about the columns. I'll try. thanks

Comment: You are putting .row directly inside .row which is wrong as per documentation. Also right now as per what your desired output is I have no idea whatsoever why you even would want to nest rows. It just doesnt make any sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104784/discussion-between-user3494047-and-reinder).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works:

```
<div class="row comment root" id="1">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div  class="col-xs-1 arrows-block">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <img src="/images/icon_up_arrow.png" name="up" class="img-responsive resize">
                <img src="/images/icon_down_arrow.png" name="down" class="img-responsive resize">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    user 1 
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    text 1
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0)">reply</a></li>
                        <li><a class="expand" href="javascript:void(0)"> expand</a></li>
                        <li><a class="delete" href="javascript:void(0)"> delete</a></li>
                        <li><a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0)"> edit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- col md 12 -->
<div class="row comment root" id="1">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div  class="col-xs-1 arrows-block">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <img src="/images/icon_up_arrow.png" name="up" class="img-responsive resize">
                    <img src="/images/icon_down_arrow.png" name="down" class="img-responsive resize">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        user 2 
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        text 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li><a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0)">reply</a></li>
                            <li><a class="expand" href="javascript:void(0)"> expand</a></li>
                            <li><a class="delete" href="javascript:void(0)"> delete</a></li>
                            <li><a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0)"> edit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- col md 12 -->
</div><!-- comment row -->
```

with the same css as in the question